# get widget number from array dynamically

Tags: php, widgets

I have widget data in var `$data = get_option('widget_as_about_me_widget')`

The widget number  is `5`. 
How to get widget number dynamically from this array?

```
array(2) {
  [5]=>
  array(56) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["image_url"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["imagealt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["heading"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["sub_heading"]=>
    string(16) "fashion designer"
    ["aboutdescription"]=>
    string(122) "Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum."
    ["extended_page"]=>
    string(5) "10853"
    ["read_more_text"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_facebook"]=>
    string(7) "jfghfhg"
    ["author_twitter"]=>
    string(8) "cnvnvbnv"
    ["author_google"]=>
    string(10) "nvnvnvbnvn"
    ["author_linkedin"]=>
    string(5) "gdfgf"
    ["author_tumblr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_pinterest"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_youtube"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_skype"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_instagram"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_delicious"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_reddit"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_stumbleupon"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_wordpress"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_vimeo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_flickr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_github"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_stack_overflow"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_xing"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_foursquare"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_paypal"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_yelp"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_soundcloud"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_lastfm"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_dribbble"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_steam"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_behance"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_weibo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_renren"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_dropbox"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_bitbucket"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_trello"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_ok"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_vk"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_home"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["shadow"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["img_border"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["border_width"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["border_color"]=>
    string(7) "#ffffff"
    ["stroke_opacity"]=>
    string(3) "0.3"
    ["select"]=>
    string(7) "hexagon"
    ["hex_flat_top"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["image_width"]=>
    string(3) "142"
    ["font_color"]=>
    string(7) "#939393"
    ["icon_color"]=>
    string(7) "#fcfcfc"
    ["icon_bg_color"]=>
    string(7) "#cccccc"
    ["icon_color_hover"]=>
    string(7) "#dd3333"
    ["widget_id"]=>
    string(20) "as_about_me_widget-5"
    ["aswidget_id"]=>
    string(20) "as_about_me_widget-5"
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

get data from first item an associative array:

```
$data = array_values(get_option('widget_as_about_me_widget'))[0];
```

how to use:

```
$data['select']
```